# Error of 'TypeError: storage.ref is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Here is the buttonUploadClicked function, and I have imported firebasestorage as `const storage = firebase.storage;` But still the error is there

This function is run when a button is clicked and error shows only when the button is clicked

**Code is below**

```js
const handleUpload = () => {
  var imageName = Math.random(0, 10000) * Math.random(0, 100);
  if (image) {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${imageName}.jpg`).put(image);

    uploadTask.on(
      'state_changed',
      (snapshot) => {
        // progress function beta

        const progressP = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        setProgress(progressP);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        storage
          .ref('images')
          .child(`${imageName}.jpg`)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((imageUrl) => {
            db.collection('posts').add({
              timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              caption: caption,
              photoUrl: imageUrl,
              username: user.email.replace('@gmail.com', '').replace('.', ''),
              picUrl: user.photoURL,
            });
          });
      },
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Please share the code of initializing the firebase storage. You can hide the credentials.

Comment: here `const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBgHeUt6SEuESwZkoK-83qq2DvYDgXmZU4",
  authDomain: "vimedia-d7580.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "vimedia-d7580",
  storageBucket: "vimedia-d7580.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1000565187437",
  appId: "1:1000565187437:web:3ecd53b6a7e548a9e63064"
};`

Comment: Where and how are you initializing your firebase?
What firebase package are you using? Also you should remove your config values...

Comment: Welcome to SO. When responding to others, please include their name preceded with and at sign, like @Jay. Also, avoid adding code to comments - it's really hard to read. Update the question with that code. It will also help future readers locate the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
const storage = firebase.storage;
```

by

```
const storage = firebase.storage();
```

The `"()"` should do the trick - you need no reference to "firebase.storage" itself, but to that what is "produced" by it.

Comment: Thank you so much!